# CSS - Button with two cut off corners

Tags: html, css

[image: Button cut off corners sample]

Hi all, I want to create a `<button>` like the one you can see in the above image, with `background: transparent; border: 1px solid #999`. I have checked a previous similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13545192/create-border-with-two-cut-off-corners) with the same problem, but since it's 3 years old I would to check if there are better solutions.

Do you have an idea on how to achieve this result? Thanks in advance for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this with `:before` and `:after` **pseudo elements**

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
button {
  padding: 20px 45px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  color: #999999;
}
button:before, button:after {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background: white;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
}
button:before {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-right: 1px solid #999999;
  transform: rotate(49deg) translate(-71%);
}
button:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #999999;
  transform: rotate(49deg) translate(71%);
}
```

```html
<button>CLICK ME</button>
```

Or you can use **SVG**

```css
button {
  display: inline-block;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
polygon {
  stroke: #999999;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke-width: 1px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
text {
  fill: #999999;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
button:hover polygon {
  fill: black;
}
button:hover text {
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <svg width="200px" height="100px">
    <polygon  points="165.083,84.769 15.971,84.769 15.971,28.227 33.742,11.263 185.114,11.263 185.114,66.837 "/>
    <text x="100" text-anchor="middle" y="55">CLICK ME</text>
  </svg>
</button>
```

Comment: This gets pretty close, but on retina monitors (and possibly others with subpixel rendering) the pseudo element's border does not perfectly meet the parent's border.

Comment: Same as @Vincent G, it's pretty close, but it would be cool to have it with a transparent background

Comment: I can't see it on my monitor but it can be adjusted with `transform: rotate() translate();`

Comment: @d_z90 i updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a JS fiddle with a little trick I use with `:before` and `:after`.

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qLjoxbg/3/)

```
button { background: #fff; padding: 8px 10px; border: 1px solid #333; box-shadow: none; position: relative;  }

button:before {content: ""; width: 10px; height: 15px; position: absolute; border-right: 1px solid #333; left: -5px; top: -6px; transform: rotate(45deg); background: #fff}

button:after {content: ""; width: 10px; height: 15px; position: absolute; border-left: 1px solid #333; right: -5px; bottom: -6px; transform: rotate(45deg); background: #fff}
```

You can replace background of `:before` and `:after` with yours to fit it correctly.

Comment: This gets pretty close, but on retina monitors (and possibly others with subpixel rendering) the pseudo element's border does not perfectly meet the parent's border.

Comment: It's a good solution, but if you set `background: transparent` it doesn't look good anymore.

Answer (score -2):

you should not use transparent background you should use url property like this

```css
.selector{
    background: url(imageAddress);
  }
```

Comment: Can you explain why? OP isn't trying to create the button with the use of an image, but with the use of borders.

Comment: I was also thinking to use a `svg` as image, but first I want to see if it's possible to make it in pure `css`